# Scrollbar ItemsControl fill vertically and then scroll horizontal

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ItemsControl with Items. I want the Items to be ordered like in the picture. If there are more elements, that space, there should be a horizontal scrollbar. How do I archive this?

[image]
Relevant code:

```
 <ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
      <ScrollViewer PanningMode="Both" >
        <ItemsPresenter />
       </ScrollViewer>
      </ControlTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.Template>
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

---

Edit:
I'm sorry that  reported that the suggested solutions did not work, turns out the Height of the Items was Changing dynamically on runtime, resulting in only space for one item vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would something like this work ?

```
<ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
      <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
           VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
```

and if that doesnt work, try this

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
          Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}, 
          Path=ActualHeight}" />
```

**EDIT**

don't forget to make your WrapPanel `Orientation="Vertical"`

Answer (score 1):

Sample code for your problem

```
<ItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Height="100" Width="200">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Template>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="100"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Hope this was thing that you were looking for !!!

Comment: This is not working as intended. I updated the my picture to clarify the problem.

Comment: Its not working after giving fix height to WrapPanel and setting Orientation to Vertical and fix height and width to ScrollViewer?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

With ListBox its simply:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"  />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```